# перенос сайта wordpress с хостинга на выделенный сервер

Tags: wordpress, сервер, ssl

Переносил сайт с хостинга на выделенный сервер, на сервере я отдельно установил wp потом копировал туда только wp-content из хостинга, ну и прописал данные бд, сейчас функция get_template_directory_uri() берет url сайта который на хостинге. Это из за того что на сервере еще нет домена и открываю через айпишник ? Или другая причина ?

Comment: Домен пропиши в [hosts](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts) и сразу делай сайт на домене. А переносить правильнее с пом плагина, который показал KAGG Design

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В WordPress все внутренние ссылки прописаны жестко в базе. Для переноса надо изменить все ссылки внутри базы (со старого url хостинга на новый). Чтобы не повредить сериализованные данные и не сломать сайт, лучше всего воспользоваться плагином [Duplicator](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/).

Comment: Спасибо большое) не знал, что в базе хранятся

Comment: Ну а где же? Все посты, страницы, виджеты, данные пользователя - все в базе.